# How to make an http response in python in google cloud functions

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

How can I tell my function to respond to an endpoint specified on the received message with a HTTP Post response in Google Cloud function? In the code, or the trigger configuration, or in the package json?

I think I'm looking for something [like this](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http) but in python:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is just this -
**return Response('No file uploaded', status=500**)
Check this out - 
https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/51515/flask.Response

FYI, A Google Cloud Function uses a Flask Response object - 
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.make_response

Answer (score 0):

This is the link to google's answer: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http
I used this link to write this solution:

```
    headers= {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
        }


    id1= "1234567"
    var1= "variable 1"

    text = '{"id1":"'+id1+'","var1":"'+var1+'"}'
    print(text)
    return (text, 200, headers)
```